Can we add an image inside a textbox without the use of a stack in swiftui?
I am trying to add an image into my textinput in swiftui without the use of a zstack because this cause the whole view to bug, this is the expected result , is there a way to add them without the use of a stack? or should i adapt the whole code based on it ?
                                HStack {
                                    ZStack {
                                        CustomTextField(placeholder: "Email", text: $email, textColor: .black, isValid: emailValid)
                                            .focused($isEmailFocused)
                                        
                                        if let isValid = emailValid {
                                            Image(isValid ? "check_solid" : "cancel_solid")
                                                .resizable()
                                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                                .foregroundColor(isValid ? Color("greenstrokes") : Color("redstrokes"))
                                                .position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100, y: 75)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


Have you tried removing the ZStack and adding a Spacer() after the CustomTextField?

How about showing the image as an overlay over the CustomTextField, using alignment: .trailing?

Is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058490/ ?

While the overlay is the way to go for placing and aligning the image over the textfield, you should consider creating a view modifier for validation, so you can apply it to any textfield.
Otherwise, you will have repeated code and overlays everywhere, if you have multiple fields.
Here's a rough example that uses a view extension and a view modifier:
import SwiftUI

struct ValidateTextFieldView: View {
    
    @State private var inputText: String = ""
    @State private var inputNumber: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            TextField("Type yes to confirm", text: $inputText)
                .padding()
                .background(.white)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
                .validateTextField($inputText)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
            
            Text("Press Enter to validate field")
                .font(.caption)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                .padding(.leading)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background(.background.secondary)
    }
}

extension View {
    
    func validateTextField(_ text: Binding<String>) -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(ValidateTextFieldModifier(text: text))
    }
}

struct ValidateTextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    //Parameters
    @Binding var text: String
    
    //State values
    @State private var isValid: Bool = false
    @State private var showValidation: Bool = false
    @State private var validationColor: Color = .clear
    
    //Body
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: text) {
                validationColor = .yellow
            }
            .onSubmit {
                if text == "yes" { //add your own validation logic
                    validationColor = .green
                }
                else { //if not valid
                    validationColor = .red
                }
            }
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8) // Rounded rectangle with a border
                    .stroke(validationColor, lineWidth: 2)
            )
            .overlay(alignment: . trailing) {
                Image(systemName: validationColor == .green ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : validationColor == .red ? "xmark.circle.fill" :  "")
                        .foregroundStyle(validationColor)
                        .padding(.trailing)
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ValidateTextFieldView()
}

I used a state to set the color depending on the validation result, but normally, you'd have a more refined method, like maybe using an enum for validation state, additional validation functions, maybe more parameters, etc.

i think the best way is to use an overlay like this :
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
                                HStack {
                                    CustomTextField(placeholder: "Email", text: $email, textColor: .black, isValid: emailValid)
                                        .focused($isEmailFocused)
                                        .overlay(
                                            Group {
                                                if let isValid = emailValid {
                                                    Image(isValid ? "check_solid" : "cancel_solid")
                                                        .resizable()
                                                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                                        .foregroundColor(isValid ? Color("greenstrokes") : Color("redstrokes"))
                                                        .padding(.trailing, 8)
                                                }
                                            },
                                            alignment: .trailing
                                        )
                                }

